# Does Citrus Framework for Integration testing(Java) supports Object to Object Asserts as in Junit?

Tags: citrus-framework

I am working on Citrus Integration Testing for a Web-service. I need to use the same DB used by the application. I am wondering if I can get response in Citrus in form of Objects, so that I can use the Object in Assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citrus is able to automatically map message payloads into domain objects. You need to setup a marshaller (Xml) or object mapper (Json) in Citrus. Then you will be able to use domain object instances in send and receive operations.

See these samples for details:

https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-databind
https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-oxm

Hope this helps